# How can I create an event-based (per x happenings) Stripe subscription plan as opposed to a time interval-based (per x months) one?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am rather new to Stripe and would like to create a Stripe plan where a customer must pay every 4 lessons. However, there is no specified time interval where the customer must complete these lessons. Is there any way to specify intervals by 'events' rather than per month/year/etc?

To create a Stripe plan, we can specify its time interval (day/week/month/year). However, I am stuck on finding out how to create intervals by lessons taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metered billing facility in stripe.You can create a plan which counts usage per day.Through metered billing you subscribe the user to a plan and charge the user by their usage of service.
Steps:

- Create a metered billing plan which calculates usage per day for a subscribed user.
- Create a customer(by create customer API) and a metered subscription(create subscription API) for that user.
- Whenever the user completes 4 lessons, hit the usage reporting API of stripe, which would create usage and would charge according to the subscription plan.
- You can define the charges for each usage according to your need.

Read [Metered Billing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing/thresholds) for stripe

- [Create Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=python)
- [Create Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=python)
- [Create Usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create?lang=python)

To get more information about stripe apis
Refer to this : [Stripe APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/)

You can mention the units that have been used by the user and you can charge per unit according to your need. (i.e. 4 units * $1.99)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please also upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to rethink your flow here. If you just want to charge your customer every 4th lesson, why not just keep track of that yourself and then do a one off charge when you're ready?

Stripe Billing can keep track of what your users are using via [metered billing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing), however you still need to set an interval period (day/week/month/year).

What would stop a user from completing 3 lessons and then disappearing before they need to pay?